# Elasticsearch term aggregation with range doc count

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to aggregate a field and return only those buckets in which doc count is within 10 to 20 for e.g.

So far from documentation it says that we can provide `min_doc_count` parameter.

Is there any way we can provide `max_doc_count` also so i only get required buckets ?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to investigate the [bucket selector pipeline aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the following query to filter the buckets using [bucket_selector](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html) aggregation. You can take a deep look at pipeline aggregations and buckets paths [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline.html#buckets-path-syntax).

In the following example i am aggregating the document on product.name field where product is of type object for me.

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "values": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "product.name.raw",
                "size": 10
            },
            "aggs": {
                "final_filter": {
                    "bucket_selector": {
                        "buckets_path": {
                            "values": "_count"
                        },
                        "script": "params.values > 10 && params.values < 20"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps
Thanks

Comment: I love you bro you are awesome :D

Comment: hi, how to check for filter by key, where key is a string ,and i want to filter if that key contains certain word ?